# JavaコードでCRLによる証明書の有効性検証の方法

Tags: java

CRLの証明書検証の方法を探してます。

以下のX509CRLクラスを使用するとわかりましたが、それでどのように証明書検証を行うかがわかりません。
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509CRL.html

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509CRL.html にありますよう、CRLファイルを読み込み、CRLのインスタンス取得方法まではこのままですので、あとはCRLのインスタンスに、検証したい証明書のインスタンスを渡す isRevoked() を使います。

```
// X509 PKI管理ファクトリの生成
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

// CRLファイルの読み込み
InputStream ins = new FileInputStream(new File("./crl.crl"));

// CRLのインスタンス
X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) factory.generateCRL(ins);

// チェック対象の証明書
InputStream ins2 = new FileInputStream(new File("./client.crt");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(ins2);

// 証明書が失効されているかを判定する
boolean revoke = crl.isRevoked(cert);
```

ご確認ください

Comment: 確認できました。ありがとうございました。